# After moving document root, pages can't be found

Tags: 8, installation

Drupal 8 installed on shared hosting.  To access the site from the web during development, I installed D8 in `/www/d7/d8`.

Then I moved `d8`, which contains the D8 install, to `/www/d8` and then set my document root in Cpanel to `d8`.

The theme and blocks load, and I can fill out the form at `/user/login`, but after that, every time I try to access a page, I get an "access denied" message and the link is pointing at `mysite.com/d8/page` instead of `mysite.com/page`.

I looked in `settings.php` and `.htaccess` but I couldn't find any references to a base directory.

How can I get my D8 site working after moving the directory and changing the document root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser cache was the issue.  Resetting the cache made everything go back to normal.